# Check for pending reboots

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to detect if the OS is pending a reboot because of updates, feature installs ...etc?

Using .NET 4 and at least need a way to detect for Win 7, 8x, Server 2008, 2012

Answer (score 1):

There is no one way to do this. There is a series of checks you should do. See http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-PendingReboot-Query-bdb79542 and the blog post which explains the code: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/06/10/determine-pending-reboot-statuspowershell-style-part-1/. This is a powershell-script doing those checks. If powershell is not an option, it should be fairly straightfoward to rewrite it in C#.